# How to write EXPRESSION for main contours in Mapfile?

Tags: mapserver, expression, mapfile

I'm working with mapfile. I defined new layer "contours" and I want to render with maxscale = 100000 and minscale = 50000 contours with value distance of 50. That means that I want in that scale render only those countours with values of "height" attribute of 0, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350.. etc.

```
LAYER
 NAME "contours"
 TYPE line
 STATUS off
 DATA "contours.shp"

 CLASS
   NAME "all_contours"
   STYLE
     COLOR 176 226 255
   END

  #Is this CLASS I started creating correct? 

   CLASS
       NAME "main_contours"
       MAXSCALE 99000
       MINSCALE 50000
       EXPRESSION #this is my question

   END
END
```

Comment: What version of MapServer are you using?

Comment: I'm using MapServer 6.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That should work using modulo:

```
EXPRESSION ( ([height] % 50) = 0 )
```

Comment: +1. Very clever solution. Also note the `MAXSCALE` and `MINSCALE` keyworks have been deprecated so use the `MAXSCALEDENOM` and `MINSCALEDENOM` instead.

Comment: Thank you. If I'm using older version of Mapserver, can I use the same expression or something different?

Comment: Seems like MapServer 5 had a bug related to the modulo operator: http://osgeo-org.1803224.n2.nabble.com/expressions-modulus-or-modulo-operator-td1993365.html - so it depends on if it has been fixed in your version.

Comment: Is the modulo operator described in the MapServer expressions on the web page?